# scp to rsync conversion

Tags: rsync, scp

The following is working as expected.

```
scp -o IdentityFile=/home/companyuser/.ssh/id_dsa_fner {} companyuser@14.140.100.189:/home/fner/
```

But the rsync version of the same command does not work:

```
rsync -av -o IdentityFile=/home/companyuser/.ssh/id_dsa_fner /home/companyuser/  companycuser@14.140.100.189:/home/fner/
```

I use find -exec >> scp to copy files in the first example. I can copy all the files in one location.
But rsync will allow me to have the same directory structure on destination exactly like master host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try specifying the transfer type with -e

```
rsync -avze "ssh -o IdentityFile=/path/to/file" /sync/here/ root@remotehost:/to/here
```